# How use stream instead for loop and benefit of that

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two Object Array `data1` and `data2`.
And I filter betwine my data using for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data1.size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < data2.size(); j++) {

                if (data1.get(i).getId().equals(data2.get(j).getID())) {

                    data1.get(i).setHome(data2.get(j).getHome());

                }

            }

        }
```

Everting work very well but I want to optimize code I want to use the `stream` instead the for loop.

Comment: Code optimization questions are better asked at [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't provide a `zip` method for the `Stream` API. An alternate that you can use is like this:

```
data1.stream().forEach(data1 -> { 
        IntStream.range(0, data2.size()).forEach(value -> {
            if (data1.getId().equals(data2.get(value).getID())) {
                data1.setHome(data2.get(value).getHome());
            }
        });
 });
```

Or simply:

```
data1.stream().forEach(data1 -> { 
            data2.forEach(data2 -> {
                if (data1.getId().equals(data2.getID())) {
                    data1.setHome(data2.getHome());
                }
            });
});
```

Or:

```
IntStream.range(0, data1.size()).forEach(i -> {
        IntStream.range(0, data2.size()).forEach(j -> {
            if (data1.get(i).getId().equals(data2.get(j).getID())) {
                data1.get(i).setHome(data2.get(j).getHome());
            }            
        });
 });
```

Comment: You don't really need a `stream` to use `forEach` in your second code block.

Comment: @Naman, you're right. I was just copy-pasting and so this happened.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to optimize code. I want to use the stream instead the for loop.

Those two things are not necessarily the same.

- In this case, simple nested loop is likely be faster AND more efficient than the direct equivalent formulation with streams.
- If you use `parallel` in the stream formulation, the stream formulation could be faster, but it won't be more efficient.  (You will be using more CPU cycles per unit of work done than in the non-parallel case.)

Let us step back and look at the actual algorithm:

- You current algorithm is comparing every element of one list with every element of the other one.  That is complexity `O(MN)` where M and N are the list sizes.
- With streams (non-parallel) the complexity is the same.
- With streams and parallelism, there *could* be a factor of up to `P` speedup, where `P` is the number of physical processors.  But that assumes that:

  1. the `P` processors are all available and used during the processing,
  2. the list sizes are large enough that the overheads of parallelization (e.g. partitioning the lists) are insignificant, and
  3. there are no confounding 2nd order effects such as memory bus contention or garbage collection.
- If we assume that the ids of the objects in the lists are unique, then you can `break` out of the inner loop when you get a match.  That gives a roughly fact of 2 improvement in performance.
- We can replace the inner loop with a lookup using a `Map` (TreeMap`or`HashMap`) of E elements built from one of the lists.

  - With a `TreeMap`, the complexity of a lookup is `O(log E)` and the complexity of building the map is `O(ElogE)`.  The overall complexity will be ``O(N'logM')` where N' is the larger of M and N and M' is the smaller.
  - With a `HashMap`, the complexity of a lookup is `O(1)` and the complexity of building the map is `O(E)`. The overall complexity will be `O(N')` where N' is the larger of M and N.
  - For large enough M and N, using a map will be more efficient.
  - If you can replace one of the lists entirely with a map, then you can avoid having to rebuild the map "each time" you run the code.
  - **However** both require `O(M')` additional space to represent the map.
- An alternative to using a Map would be to do an in-place sort of both lists, to get them into id order.  Then you iterate over the two lists using a merge algorithm, and make the required change when entries match.  This has roughly `O(N'logN')` complexity where N' is the larger of M and N, and it uses no extra space.  (Assuming that the sort is genuinely in-place.)  But this is also more complicated.

---

So here is my optimization based on the above:

```
// This assumes `list2` is the smaller of the lists.  If you don't know
// which one is likely to be smaller, you may need two versions of the code.

Map<Id, Record> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Record record: list2) {
    map.put(record.getId(), record);
}

for (Record record: list1) {
    Record record2 = map.get(record.getId());
    if (record2 != null) {
        record.setHome(record2.getHome());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Imo, there is no real benefit to using streams since you aren't duplicating any data structures as temporary holding facilities. But you can make it cleaner and more efficient by doing two things.

1. Base the inner for loop's index off of the outer loop's to avoid rechecking already checked IDs.
2. Retrieve the types you are working with to make the comparisons less cluttered and less prone to mistakes.

Having made up `MyDataClass` and the `ID` type for demonstration, this works just fine.

```java
      for (int i = 0; i < data1.size() - 1; i++) {

         MyDataClass d1 = data1.get(i);
         Integer id = d1.getID();

         for (int j = i + 1; j < data2.size(); j++) {

            MyDataClass d2 = data2.get(j);

            if (id.equals(d2.getID())) {
               d1.setHome(d2.getHome());
            }
         }
      }

      System.out.println(data1);
```

Streams and lambdas are very useful capabilities.  But not all situations benefit from their use.

Answer (score 0):

@Shankha057 is technically correct. But actual power of streams is its rich api.
You can do comething like :

```java
data1.parallelStream().forEach(data1 -> { 
            data2.parallelStream()
                 .filter(data2 -> data1.getId().equals(data2.getID()))
                 .forEach(data2 -> data1.setHome(data2.getHome())); // Synchronize this if you expect multiple matches
            });
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: The `parallelStream()` although it uses the common fork-join pool. The problem is that if the operation is a long running one, you are effectively blocking all the threads in the pool. Additionally, the entire classloader has to use this pool if specified and you cannot supply your own thread pool as well.

Comment: I would use `parallelStream` only if I am 100% sure that my work can be finished in a short amount of time. Or else, I won't use it and wait for Oracle to make ways to allow passing our own thread pool for `parallelStream`